# Should I use missing value using imputation or listwise or pairwise deletion methods?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have 60,000 data and around 45% of them is missing and the missing values are random. Can I simply use listwise or pairwise deletion or do I have to use imputation? If imputation is recommended which imputation is the best one?

Comment: I'm curious what precisely you mean by "missing values are random" and how you know it.  I recommend Andrew Gelman's [chapter on imputation](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on

1. Amount of missing data (what percentage of data is missing)
2. Type of missing data (MAR, MCAR, NMAR)

According to [this nice article](http://edmeasurement.net/5245/Tsikriktsis-2005.pdf) (Tsikriktsis: A review of techniques for treating missing data in OM survey research, 2005), if more than 10% data is missing, the best solution is

1. Maximum likelihood imputation if data are NMAR (non-missing at random)
2. Maximum likelihood and hot-deck if data are MAR (missing at random)
3. Pairwise deletion, hot-deck or regression if data are MCAR (missing completely at random)

Comment: Looks like an interesting article, thanks for the link.

Comment: Multiple imputation is conspicuous in its absence from the linked paper. It's not mentioned at all.

Comment: Hello. I'm having some difficulty opening the link to the article you shared. Would you be kind enough to post a new link or let me know the title of the article so I can manually search for it? Thank you.

Comment: The first link should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

In short: If your data is missing completely at random (**MCAR**), i.e., a true value of a missing value has the same distribution as an observed variable and missingness cannot be predicted from any other variables, your results will be **unbiased but inefficient** using listwise or pairwise deletion.

**Multiple imputation by chained equations** is regarded the best imputation method by many researchers.